# How to write temporary files in memory (python)

Tags: python, scipy, wav, wave

I'm writing program which process audio data (WAV files 150-300 ms long) in a loop.
Now I:

1. Get data
2. Write WAV file
3. Read WAV file
4. Process data

How can I make this process easier and faster? I'm thinking about storing WAV file data in memory, so in this case I do not need to read files (3 step).

Trick is that I need WAV files to process. So it is needed to process raw data to WAV.

My code is here:

```
import pyaudio
import crepe
import os
import wave
from scipy.io import wavfile
import time as tm

# Hide TF logging
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

CHUNK = 1024 * 4
WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000


try:
    conf_list = []
    looptime_list = []
    print("Recording is starting...")
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
    while True:
        start_time = tm.time()
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)

        wf = wave.open('audiofile.wav', 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(WIDTH * 2)  # somehow it's not 2 but 4
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(data)
        wf.close()

        audio = wavfile.read('audiofile.wav')[1]

        time, frequency, confidence, activation = crepe.predict(audio, RATE, model_capacity="tiny", step_size=130, verbose=0)

        if len(time) > 1:
            print("few steps in one chunk")
            for n in range(0, len(time)):
                conf_list.append(confidence[n])
                confidence_mark = ""
                if confidence[n] >= 0.4:
                    confidence_mark = ""
                print(f"{confidence_mark} {round(frequency[n])} Hz | {round(confidence[n], 2)}")
        else:
            conf_list.append(confidence[0])
            confidence_mark = ""
            if confidence[0] >= 0.4:
                confidence_mark = ""
            print(f"{confidence_mark} {round(frequency[0])} Hz | {round(confidence[0], 2)}")


        looptime_list.append(tm.time() - start_time)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    print('Recording stopped')
    av_conf = round(sum(conf_list) / len(conf_list), 2)
    av_lt = round(sum(looptime_list) / len(looptime_list), 5)
    print(f"Average accuracy: {av_conf}\n"
          f"Average time on chunk processing: {av_lt}")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, it would be easier for us to help you if you can provide a smallest run-able example to demo your concerns.  If need you can read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  For your code there are some issues in your code.  1. the main part is try to avoid open the file again and again within a loop. That is the most concern part. 2. just read wav date, which is just an array of numbers. You can process the data in memory. which should be very fast and you should not have any run time performance issue..

Comment: Because I don't understand your goal, nor able to run your code, it seems there are even steam-related things, which might incur different issues. Thus I could not fix your code but point out the most obvious issues there.

Comment: Take a look at the `@cache` decorator from [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) and provide more information/code so we can provide a better answer.

Comment: python has `io.Bytes()` and `io.String()` to create file-like objects in memory - but not all functions can use it instead of filename.

Comment: `wave.open` supports file-like objects, so see @furas comment